# where can I find an app styleguide?

Tags: mobile

I am creating a mobile styleguide that will make it easier for other departments to design apps similarly - not totally the same as in using the same template. Eg. using standard colors in jewels, backgrounds, common fonts, etc. Since it's pretty new, I am having hard time looking for a good styleguide examples. I am not looking for a guide for developers but guide for another to design another app using the styles set.

Answer (score 5):

[The BBC Global Experience Language](http://www.bbc.co.uk/gel).

[The Apple iOS Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html)

[Guidelines for common user interactions for Windows Store apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465370.aspx)

[Android design guidelines](http://developer.android.com/design/index.html)

[Smashing Magazine: Designing Style Guidelines for Brands and Websites](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/21/designing-style-guidelines-for-brands-and-websites/)

Comment: Take special note of the official platform style guidelines.  One of your style guide guidelines should be "follow the platform styleguide." In the case of iPhone apps, I've heard that not following Apple's guidelines may result in app rejection.

Answer (score 2):

It's not for an app but the [style guide for Starbucks' responsive site](http://www.starbucks.com/static/reference/styleguide/) is incredibly useful and worth emulating.